# Can Bayes algorithm be used for regression problem?

Tags: linear-regression, naivebayes

I am a student and i got an assignment on Bayes algorithm. So i found some information about Bayes classification problem but i want to know whether this algorithm can solve regression problem or not.

I want to know about it

Comment: This thread will have answers to your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218492/how-does-naive-bayes-work-with-continuous-variables. TL;DR, yes, you may use Naive Bayes for regression.